# PHP upload failing to upload to server

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

I am trying to write an upload script to drop a file into the server and echo the value into the database... needless to say its not working and its returning the echo at the bottom of the script. I have no idea whats wrong with it :/

```
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('..', '..', '..', '..');
        $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO event-archive SET (`title`,`date`,`time_start`,`time_end`,`region`,`description`,`sponsors`,`embed`,`event-type`,`recording-type`,`additional-information`) VALUES (' . addslashes($_POST['title']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['date']) . ',' . intval($_POST['time-start']) . ',' . intval($_POST['time-end']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['region']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['description']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['sponsors']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['embed']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['event-type']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['recording-type']) . ',' . addslashes($_POST['additional-information']) . ')');

        if (isset($_FILES["sponsors"])){
            $target_dir = "path";
            $info = new SplFileInfo($target_dir . basename($_FILES["sponsors"]));
            $newfile = time() . '.' . $info->getExtension();
            $target_file = $target_dir . $newfile;

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sponsors"], $target_file)) {
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }

        $mysqli->close();
        exit;
    }
```

I have the enctype on the form and, all of the rest of the data is being posted correctly.

Comment: Please follow the this link on how to properly upload files in php.http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp Alternative, you can print_r($_FILE) to see if you file is actually passed through

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi That's `print_r($_FILES)` in plural form.

Comment: @fred.. typo... corrected... thanks

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. `addslashes` is nowhere nearly sufficient for this task.

Answer (score -1):

```
 If( isset($_FILES["sponsors"]["name"])){}
```

This checks that the file name is actually passed through

The link belows explains explicitly how file upload is handled in PHP http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: that isn't the only thing wrong with the guy's code, there's a LOT more to address.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I add a link for him to revise his code whilst studying